Remove Gaps in Chart
I have the following diagram:

data = {
    'start': ['2024-08-02 08:00', '2024-08-02 09:00', '2024-08-02 18:50'],
    'ende':  ['2024-08-02 09:00', '2024-08-02 18:50', '2024-08-03 10:00'],
    'color': ['green', 'green','green', 'green', 'green']
}

Here is the Python code that generates the diagram:
def createBarChart(df):
    # Convert the columns ‘start’ and ‘end’ into datetime objects
    df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
    df['ende'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ende'])

    # Create Diagramm
    fig = go.Figure()

    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=[row['start'], row['ende'], row['ende'], row['start']],
            y=[1, 1, 0, 0],
            fill='toself',
            fillcolor=row['color'],
            mode='none',  
            showlegend=False,

        ))

    # Formatting the x-axis
    tickvals = pd.date_range(start=df['start'].min(), end=df['ende'].max(), freq='3H')
    ticktext = []
    previous_day = None

    for d in tickvals:
        if previous_day is None or d.day != previous_day:
            ticktext.append(f"<b>{d.strftime('%d.%m')}</b>")
        else:
            ticktext.append(d.strftime('%H:%M'))
        previous_day = d.day

    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
        xaxis=dict(
            tickformat='%H:%M',
            tickvals=tickvals,
            ticktext=ticktext
        ),
        margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=10, b=20),
        height=200,

    )

    return fig

Now we come to the problem. To display the diagram, I read from a CSV file. Each line in the CSV file is a block. The last two blocks are green. However, there is a small line between these two, which I would like to remove so that it is a continuous green bar.

Could you please share the data you are using?

I have tried it with the data mentioned above answer,
So, assuming your data is like:
data = {
    'start': ['2024-08-27 08:00', '2024-08-27 09:00', '2024-08-27 10:00', '2024-08-27 11:00', '2024-08-27 12:00'],
    'ende':  ['2024-08-27 09:00', '2024-08-27 10:00', '2024-08-27 11:00', '2024-08-27 12:00', '2024-08-27 13:00'],
    'color': ['green', 'green','green', 'green', 'green']
}

and modified function will be:
def createBarChart(df):
    # Convert the columns 'start' and 'end' into datetime objects
    df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
    df['ende'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ende'])

    # Sorting the data
    df = df.sort_values(by='start').reset_index(drop=True)

    # Merge consecutive blocks with the same color
    merged_df = []
    current_start = df.loc[0, 'start']
    current_end = df.loc[0, 'ende']
    current_color = df.loc[0, 'color']

    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, 'color'] == current_color and df.loc[i, 'start'] == current_end:
            current_end = df.loc[i, 'ende']
        else:
            merged_df.append({'start': current_start, 'ende': current_end, 'color': current_color})
            current_start = df.loc[i, 'start']
            current_end = df.loc[i, 'ende']
            current_color = df.loc[i, 'color']

    # Don't forget to append the last block
    merged_df.append({'start': current_start, 'ende': current_end, 'color': current_color})

    # Convert merged_df to a DataFrame
    merged_df = pd.DataFrame(merged_df)

    # Create a figure diagram
    fig = go.Figure()

    for i, row in merged_df.iterrows():
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=[row['start'], row['ende'], row['ende'], row['start']],
            y=[1, 1, 0, 0],
            fill='toself',
            fillcolor=row['color'],
            mode='none',  
            showlegend=False,
        ))

    # Formatting the x-axis
    tickvals = pd.date_range(start=merged_df['start'].min(), end=merged_df['ende'].max(), freq='3H')
    ticktext = []
    previous_day = None

    for d in tickvals:
        if previous_day is None or d.day != previous_day:
            ticktext.append(f"<b>{d.strftime('%d.%m')}</b>")
        else:
            ticktext.append(d.strftime('%H:%M'))
        previous_day = d.day

    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis=dict(showticklabels=False),
        xaxis=dict(
            tickformat='%H:%M',
            tickvals=tickvals,
            ticktext=ticktext
        ),
        margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=10, b=20),
        height=200,
    )

    return fig

and I am getting following result:


Yes, thank you, it works for me too. I was wondering if there was a little parameter you could add to make that little area disappear. Thank you.

Glad it helped. Happy coding!

This is due to the, start time of the second block does not immediately follow
So to remove the gap you can use
    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        if df.loc[i, 'color'] == df.loc[i + 1, 'color']:
            df.loc[i, 'ende'] = df.loc[i + 1, 'start']

this will ensure the end time of the current row to match the start time of the next row.
Full Code : Link
If its plotly.graph_objects default behavior then,
You can Move to alternative Library like matplotlib.pyplot and Update the code according to it.
Alternative Option: Full Code : Link

I have just tried your code. In my CSV file it is also the case that the time periods follow each other. For example: start 09:50 end 10:45; start 10:45 end 18:45; start 18:45 end 10:00.
When I run your code, I still get the dashes. I think it has to do with the width. I've already tried: line=dict(width=None), but it doesn't work for me.

Can you share the dataset that you are tiring

The same as you in the GitHub Repo:
data = {
'start': ['2024-08-27 09:50', '2024-08-27 10:45', '2024-08-27 18:45'],
'ende':  ['2024-08-27 10:45', '2024-08-27 18:45', '2024-08-27 20:00'],
'color': ['green', 'green','green']
}

it show the different segment in the plotly.graph_objects  , you can use try alternatives like matplotlib.pyplot

plotly.graph_objects i here even if use line=dict(width=0, color='rgba(0,0,0,0)') like this still it will show by default best way to handle ur requirement is finding a alternative plot library
